# A method to generate executable code randomly?

Tags: javascript, random, executable

Is there a pre existing way to randomly create executable code? For instance, a generator that creates lines of random JavaScript code that is at least grammatically correct? It could generate each word or part of the code from a list of grammatical possibilities.

In the event that a generator like this doesn't exist, I'll probably program one myself. I checked the web and couldn't find anything close, anyway. I appreciate any suggestions or thoughts on the matter!

Comment: Seems doubtful to me. The only reason such a thing would be useful it seems, would be to satisfy this question - even then the purpose of such an esoteric thing entirely eludes me.

Comment: Code generators of this kind are used, using assembly language, to generate instruction sequences used in the testing of new processor designs. By analogy, I could imagine using such a code generator for a high-level language to test a new compiler or interpreter for that language. I don't know of any publicly available tool of that nature, however.

Comment: Here is [a paper](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Brendan_Eich/publication/221137904_Tracing_for_web_3.0_trace_compilation_for_the_next_generation_web_applications/links/53e50dca0cf21cc29fca3753.pdf) describing a random code generator used for the testing of C compilers. I haven't found anything for JavaScript yet, put Google Scholar is your friend.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts. The question is certainly strange. I ask because I'd like to design an AI that improves upon itself using randomized code and evolutionary computation. The code would improve each generation of the AI by continually randomizing to some degree.

Comment: I just saw your comment, njuffa--Thanks for the help!

Comment: You'll want to work with an AST, not plain code. Look into [estree](https://github.com/estree/estree) for example that is used as the output format of many ES6 parsers. That way, generating grammatically valid code should be easy. For creating semantically valid, or even working, and useful code - well, good *luck*, may the PRNGs be with you.

Comment: For genetic algorithms, you will need a fitness metric, which would be what?

Comment: Thanks, Bergi. An AST is exactly what I'd need. As for fitness, AIs would probably be scored by the number of energy resources they gather (from food and other AI).